# Map not displaying after navigating away from page and returning

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React Js App that uses the "react-typescript-datamaps" library to display a map component. When I upload the app to the server and load the component for the first time, the data loads correctly and the map displays with no issues. However, if I visit another page and then navigate back to the page with the map, the map doesn't display anymore.

I've checked the console for errors and there aren't any. I've also tried to debug the issue by placing console logs throughout the code, but I can't seem to pinpoint where the problem is occurring.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DataMapsWrapper } from "react-typescript-datamaps";
import { Loading } from "components/shared";
import "./styles.css";
import { Button, InputGroup, Select, Tag } from "components/ui";
import {
  AiOutlineMinus,
  AiOutlinePieChart,
  AiOutlinePlus,
} from "react-icons/ai";
import ThreatsMapHeader from "./ThreatsMapHeader";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setFilterByDate, setIntervalValue } from "../store/stateSlice";
import GetCountryFromIp from "../../../utils/GetCountryFromIp";
import GetCoordinatesFromIp from "../../../utils/GetCoordinatesFromIp";
import AttackHelper from "./AttackHelper";
import BlastHelper from "./BlastHelper";
import { isEmpty } from "lodash";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { apiGetCyberThreatsMap } from "services/MapService";
import { MdDynamicFeed, MdFilterList } from "react-icons/md";
import { TbCurrentLocation } from "react-icons/tb";
import { BsArrowDownCircle, BsArrowUpCircle } from "react-icons/bs";
import CountryCard from "./CountryCard";
import CardHeader from "./CardHeader";
import BubblesConfig from "./BubblesConfig";
import ProjectionConfig from "./ProjectionConfig";

const windowMatchMedia = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");

const MapView = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [listCountriesFeeds, setListCountriesFeeds] = useState([]);
  const [listFeeds, setListFeeds] = useState([]);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [dst, setDst] = useState([]);
  const [src, setSrc] = useState([]);
  const [dstloc, setDstloc] = useState();
  const [srcloc, setSrcloc] = useState();
  const [IPv4, setIPv4] = useState();
  const [arc, setArc] = useState([]);
  const [blast, setBlast] = useState([]);

  const intervalValue = useSelector(
    (state) => state.threatsMap.state.intervalValue
  );

  const filterByDate = useSelector(
    (state) => state.threatsMap.state.filterByDate
  );

  const getThreatsMap = async () => {
    const response = await apiGetCyberThreatsMap({ filterByDate });
    if (response) {
      setData(response.data.data);
      setTotal(response.data.data.length);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getThreatsMap();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [filterByDate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading || !data[index]) return;

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setArc([]);
      setBlast([]);
      setDst(null);
      setSrc(null);
      setIPv4(null);

      const currentItem = data[index];

      if (currentItem && currentItem.Attributes) {
        const dstAttributes = currentItem.Attributes.filter(
          (item) => item.type === "ip-dst"
        );
        const srcAttributes = currentItem.Attributes.filter(
          (item) => item.type === "ip-src"
        );
        const ipv4Attribute = currentItem.Attributes.find(
          (item) => item.type === "IPv4"
        );

        const dstValues = dstAttributes.map((item) => item.value);
        const srcValues = srcAttributes.map((item) => item.value);

        setDst(dstValues);
        setSrc(srcValues);
        setIPv4(ipv4Attribute);
      }

      const executeAttack = async () => {
        if (src.length > 0) {
          const country = await GetCountryFromIp(src[0].value);
          const loc = await GetCoordinatesFromIp(src[0].value);
          setSrcloc({ country, ...loc });
        }
        if (dst.length > 0) {
          const country = await GetCountryFromIp(dst[0].value);
          const loc = await GetCoordinatesFromIp(dst[0].value);
          setDstloc({ country, ...loc });
        }
        if (src.length > 0 && dst.length > 0 && srcloc && dstloc) {
          const attack = AttackHelper(srcloc, dstloc);
          setBlast([]);
          
          setArc([attack]);
        } else if (src.length > 0 && srcloc) {
          const blast = BlastHelper(srcloc);
          setBlast([blast]);
        } else if (dst.length > 0 && dstloc) {
          const blast = BlastHelper(dstloc);
          setBlast([blast]);
        } else {
          if (IPv4) {
            const country = await GetCountryFromIp(IPv4.value);
            const loc = await GetCoordinatesFromIp(IPv4.value);
            setSrcloc({ country, ...loc });
            if (srcloc) {
              const blast = BlastHelper(srcloc);
              setBlast([blast]);
            }
          }
        }
      };

      executeAttack();
      setIndex((prev) => (prev + 1) % data.length);
    }, intervalValue);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [index, data, loading]);

  {
    /** Display Attacks Feed */
  }
  const createInterval = (setContent, contentCreator) => {
    if (!loading && !isEmpty(data)) {
      let index = 0;

      const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
        const currentData = data[index];
        const countryObj = await GetCountryFromIp(
          currentData.Attributes[0].value
        );
        const countryName = countryObj ? countryObj.country_name : "Unknown";
        const countryCode = countryObj ? countryObj.country_code : "Unknown";

        setContent((prevContent) => [
          {
            id: index,
            content: contentCreator(currentData, countryCode, countryName),
          },
          ...prevContent,
        ]);

        index = (index + 1) % data.length;
      }, intervalValue);

      return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    if (loading || isEmpty(data)) {
      setContent(() => [
        {
          id: 0,
          content: "<div>No data found</div>",
        },
      ]);
      return;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const contentCreator = (currentData, countryCode, countryName) => `
    <div class="pb-5 flex items-center">
      <a href="/events/public/overview/${
        currentData.uuid
      }" target="_blank" class="flex ">
        <div class="flex items-center mr-4">
          <img src="./map/icons/IPv4.png"  alt="Info">
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col">
        <span class='font-semibold'>${
          currentData.info.length > 65
            ? currentData.info.substring(0, 65) + "..."
            : currentData.info
        }</span>
          <div class="flex justify-left mt-1">
          <div class="flex justify-center gap-2 mt-1">
            <span>
            ${currentData.date_occured} 
            </span>
            <span
              aria-label="${countryCode}"
              role="img"
              title="${countryCode}"
              style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-image: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.3.0/flags/4x3/${countryCode.toLowerCase()}.svg'); background-position: 50% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; font-size: 1em; line-height: 1em; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 0.1em;"
            ></span>
            <strong class='text-emerald-100 dark:text-emerald-500'>${
              countryName.length > 30
                ? countryName.substring(0, 30) + "..."
                : countryName
            }</strong> [${currentData.Attributes[0].value}]
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    `;
    return createInterval(setListFeeds, contentCreator);
  }, [data, loading, intervalValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const contentCreator = (currentData, countryCode, countryName) => `
      <div>
        <div>
          <span
            aria-label="${countryCode}"
            role="img"
            title="${countryCode}"
            style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-image: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.3.0/flags/4x3/${countryCode.toLowerCase()}.svg'); background-position: 50% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; font-size: 1em; line-height: 1em; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 0.5em;"
          ></span>
          <span>${
            countryName.length > 30
              ? countryName.substring(0, 30) + "..."
              : countryName
          }</span>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 1rem;">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    `;

    return createInterval(setListCountriesFeeds, contentCreator);
  }, [data, loading, intervalValue]);

  {
    /** Filter by date range */
  }
  const filterDate = [
    { value: "last_24_hours", label: "Last 24 hours", color: "#00B8D9" },
    { value: "last_3_days", label: "Last 3 days", color: "#00B8D9" },
    { value: "last_week", label: "Last week", color: "#00B8D9" },
    { value: "last_month", label: "Last month", color: "#00B8D9" },
  ];

  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const [collapseText, setCollapseText] = useState("Collapse");
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState(
    <BsArrowUpCircle className="ml-1 rtl:mr-1" />
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setIcon(
      isCollapsed ? (
        <BsArrowDownCircle className="ml-1 rtl:mr-1" />
      ) : (
        <BsArrowUpCircle className="ml-1 rtl:mr-1" />
      )
    );
    isCollapsed
      ? setCollapseText("Open Timeline ")
      : setCollapseText("Collapse");
  }, [isCollapsed]);

  const handleCollapse = () => {
    setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    dispatch(setFilterByDate(e.value));
    dispatch(setIntervalValue(intervalValue));
    getThreatsMap({ filterByDate: e.value });
    setListFeeds([]);
    setListCountriesFeeds([]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex  items-center justify-between">
        <div className="mr-4  ">
          <ThreatsMapHeader
            totalAttacks={total}
            loading={loading}
            text={filterByDate}
          />
          <div className="text-xs">
            <CardHeader title='TOP 3 ATTACK ORIGINS' icon={<AiOutlinePieChart className="mr-2 text-lg"/>}/>
            <div>
              <CountryCard
                country_code="ru"
                country_name="United States Of America"
              />
              <CountryCard country_code="ru" country_name="Russia" />
              <CountryCard country_code="cn" country_name="China" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="text-xs">
            <CardHeader title='TOP 3 ATTACK TARGETS' icon={<AiOutlinePieChart className="mr-2 text-lg"/>}/>
            <div>
              <CountryCard country_code="sa" country_name="Saudi Arabia" />
              <CountryCard country_code="ir" country_name="Iran" />
              <CountryCard country_code="vn" country_name="Vietnam" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          style={
            windowMatchMedia.matches
              ? { width: "100vw", height: "65vh" }
              : { width: "100vw", height: "65vh" }
          }>
          <Loading loading={loading}>
            <DataMapsWrapper
              setProjectionConfig={ProjectionConfig}
              responsive
              attacks={arc}
              bubbles={blast}
              geographyConfig={{
                popupOnHover: true,
                highlightOnHover: true,
                highlightFillColor: "#FC8D59", // set highlight fill color
                highlightBorderColor: "#FC8D59", // set highlight border color
                borderColor: "#364d53",
                borderWidth: 0.5,
                dataType: "topojson",
                dataUrl: "/map/map.topojson",
                highlightBorderWidth: 3, // set highlight border width
                highlightBorderOpacity: 1, // set highlight border opacity
                highlightFillOpacity: 0.5, // set highlight fill opacity
              }}
              fills={{
                defaultFill: "#101518",
                MAJOR: "#306596",
                MEDIUM: "#0fa0fa",
                MINOR: "#bada55",
              }}
              bubblesConfig={BubblesConfig}
            />
          </Loading>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col mt-3">
        <div
          className="flex justify-start mr-2 rtl:ml-2 mb-1 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={handleCollapse}>
          <Tag
            className="bg-emerald-100 text-emerald-600 dark:bg-emerald-500/20 dark:text-emerald-100 border-0 rounded"
            suffix={icon}>
            {collapseText}
          </Tag>
        </div>

        <div className="grid grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-1">
          <div className={`text-xs col-span-1`}>
            <div
              style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0, .35)" }}
              className="h-full ">
             
              <CardHeader title='FILTERS' icon={<MdFilterList className="mr-2 text-lg"/>}/>
              <div className={`px-4 ${isCollapsed ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
                <h6 className="text-xs uppercase mb-3 mt-4 ">
                  Filter by date range
                </h6>
                <div className=" font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 mb-3">
                  <div className="" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                    <Select
                      className="mb-2"
                      placeholder="Select Date Range"
                      defaultValue={filterDate[1]}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      options={filterDate}></Select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <h6 className="text-xs uppercase mb-3 ">Filter by country</h6>
                <div className=" font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400  mb-3 ">
                  <div className="" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                    <Select
                      className="mb-2 "
                      placeholder="Select Country"
                      ></Select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <h6 className="text-xs uppercase mb-3 ">Data speed (ms)</h6>
                <InputGroup size="sm" className="">
                  <Button
                    variant="solid"
                    color={"emerald-500"}
                    onClick={() => {
                      dispatch(
                        setIntervalValue(
                          intervalValue > 100
                            ? intervalValue - 100
                            : intervalValue
                        )
                      );
                    }}>
                    <AiOutlineMinus />{" "}
                  </Button>
                  <div className="w-8 text-center font-bold text-white">
                    {intervalValue / 100}
                  </div>
                  <Button
                    variant="solid"
                    color={"emerald-500"}
                    onClick={() => {
                      dispatch(setIntervalValue(intervalValue + 100));
                    }}>
                    <AiOutlinePlus />
                  </Button>
                </InputGroup>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className={`col-span-2`}>
            <CardHeader title='LIVE ATTACKS FEEDS' icon={<MdDynamicFeed className="mr-2 text-lg"/>}/>
            <div className={`${isCollapsed ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
              <div
                className="p-2 overflow-y-scroll w-full col-span-5 lg:col-span-5 tiny-scrollbar"
                style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0, .35)", height: "40vh" }}>
                <Loading loading={loading}>
                  <div className="uppercase text-xs py-5">
                    {listFeeds.map((item) => (
                      <div
                        key={uuidv4()}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content }}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </Loading>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className={`text-xs col-span-1`}>
            <CardHeader title='LOCATIONS' icon={<TbCurrentLocation className="mr-2 text-lg"/>}/>
            <div className={`${isCollapsed ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
              <div
                className="p-2 overflow-y-scroll w-full col-span-5 lg:col-span-5 tiny-scrollbar"
                style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0, .35)", height: "40vh" }}>
                <Loading loading={loading}>
                  <div className="uppercase text-xs py-5">
                    {listCountriesFeeds.map((item) => (
                      <div
                        key={uuidv4()}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content }}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </Loading>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MapView;
```

**This issue only happens after I upload the app to the server. When running the app locally on my machine, everything works fine.**